# How to access the HTML document being generated dynamically inside an iframe, from remote server?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm creating a web application to display reports which are being fetched from `Tableau` server. I use `tableauSoftware.viz()` function to get the reports and display them.

I'm using **tableau_v8.js** file.

An `iframe` is generated dynamically using **tableau_v8.js** file. This `iframe` contains an `HTML` document that uses `dojo framework` to create *UI* components on `HTML` page.

On the click of a button on the *UI* which was generated inside the `iframe`, some new `HTML` `DIV` tags gets added dynamically.

I think these `DIV` tags are being added because of some script or functions being called on the in the `JavaScript` (i.e. **tableau_v8.js**) file or because of some request being POSTED on to the `tableau server`, but I don't have a clear understanding on how these elements are being generated.

How do I find a way to understand the dynamic creation of `HTML` document as well as other `HTML` components inside an `iframe`?

How should I go about this issue?

Comment: What exactly is your question? It certainly is possible to communicate cross-domain with an iframe, assuming you have some control over both, but from your question, i'm not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: I am not able understand as in how the HTML document gets generated inside an iframe? The code to generate the iframe is in the tableau_v8.js file, but I am not able to find anything specific in the ".js" file that can explain this creation of HTML document... Thanks for the reply, @Kevin B

Comment: Most likely the js file simply creates an iframe pointing to the other server. However, since we don't have access to said js file, we can't really tell you what it's actually doing.

Comment: Below is the link to tableau_v8.js file.                            https://github.com/devarshi150790/Problems/blob/master/y.js       And to be more specific, on the lines 669, 810, 856, 2598 and 3057, it seems an iframe is being accessed or modified, will this be of any help? @Kevin B

Comment: Not sure tbh. The way the functions are named it's hard to understand what it's doing without following it line by line from the top.

Comment: I too am not able to understand the file. Thanks for all the help, @KevinB

Comment: If you want to study a graphing tool, you might look at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). [Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/) and others have published a lot of information on how it works, including the [UW Interactive Data Lab](http://idl.cs.washington.edu/) (see [here](http://idl.cs.washington.edu/papers/d3)).